# Admob rewarded video will only appear once then the app must be restarted

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've integrated admob rewarded video into my app.

When the app is launched and I click the "watch video" button the rewarded video plays fine.

However, if I "close video" then try to "watch video" again it does not work.

Once the video is finished if I try to "watch video" again it does not work.

It seems once the video has been opened once it will not open again.

So in the SKScene I have:

```
 func videoAd() {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadAndShow3"), object: nil)
}
```

In View controller:

```
    func loadAndShow3() {

    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)

}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {


    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady {



        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }


}


func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {

    let oldCoin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
    let newCoin = oldCoin + 20
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newCoin, forKey: "COINSCORE")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        if let scene3 = GameOverMenu(fileNamed: "Gameover") {

            scene3.viewController = self
            scene3.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene3)

            scene3.coinLabel.removeFromParent()
            scene3.createCoinScore()



        }
    }


}
```

In the delegate I have:

```
 let request = GADRequest()
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate methods for the `GADRewardBasedVideoAd`.

Specifically:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
    print("Reward based video ad is closed.")
}
```

You should be building a new `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` here and requesting a new ad.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've implemented that method and put the code that's in the delegate shown above in it however whenever the ad now closes it starts up another advert without pressing the button

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, had to shuffle some of the code in the view controller around and implement Daniel's answer

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()

    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")


func loadAndShow3() {


    if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady {

        GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }

}




}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {


}


func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {

    let oldCoin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
    let newCoin = oldCoin + 20
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newCoin, forKey: "COINSCORE")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        if let scene3 = GameOverMenu(fileNamed: "Gameover") {

            scene3.viewController = self
            scene3.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene3)

            scene3.coinLabel.removeFromParent()
            scene3.createCoinScore()



        }
    }


}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {


  let request = GADRequest()
   GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")


}
```